# Pylab - what font is currently being used?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I find out, what is the active font in pylab? How can I find what is the default font in my pylab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [`rcParams`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html):

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.rcParams
...
'font.family': ['sans-serif'],
...
'font.sans-serif': ['Bitstream Vera Sans',
                    'DejaVu Sans',
                    'Lucida Grande',
                    'Verdana',
                    'Geneva',
                    'Lucid',
                    'Arial',
                    'Helvetica',
                    'Avant Garde',
                    'sans-serif'],
...
```

This means that the default font type is sans-serif, and the list above shows `matplotlib`'s preference (same as you'll see in CSS) when choosing fonts. Bitstream Vera Sans is built in `matplotlib`.

Naturally it does not affect `pgf` backend where you can set some custom font via `TeX` commands, but you are probably using the default one.

Comment: And you can change it permanently by modifying the file located at `matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()`